# Zurb's Foundation 3.2.5 based layout and extra width in some pages in Opera

Tags: html, css, opera, zurb-foundation

I use [zurb-foundation](/questions/tagged/zurb-foundation) to maintain the layout of my website. The home page of [that website](http://quran.2index.net) is rendreded perfectly in Opera 12.14 beside some other pages. However, some pages such as [this page](http://quran.2index.net/viewSura/93) has extra blank space on the right on Opera only. I tried to inspect element in the blank extra space, it mentioned to the html tag?!! I copied the html source into my editor (netbeans) to see if there some missing ending tags, but I did not find any of them. My website is rtl. What should cause this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the cause of this layout problem in Opera. It is due to [soundmanager2](/questions/tagged/soundmanager2). In Opera only it generates a div tag just before the closing body tag as follows:

```
<div id="sm2-container" class="movieContainer sm2_debug" style="position: absolute; width: 6px; height: 6px; top: -9999px; left: 9999px;">
  <embed name="sm2movie" id="sm2movie" src="/quran/themed/slate/js/swf/soundmanager2_flash9_debug.swf" quality="high" allowscriptaccess="always" bgcolor="#ffffff" pluginspage="www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" title="JS/Flash audio component (SoundManager 2)" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" haspriority="true">
</div>
```

Since I don't know how to make Soundmanager2 to stop generating this div, I decided to solve it using CSS as the following:

```
#sm2-container .movieContainer .sm2_debug{ 
 display: none; 
}
```

However, the above CSS solution fixed the layout issue, but it causes the Soundmanager stop working on Opera! Till this point, I regard this is an answer for my question about the layout.

### The Final Solurtion:

from [this answer](https://getsatisfaction.com/schillmania/topics/quirks_with_hiding_the_sm2_container) on the official SM2 forum. I have to make a div with an id sm2_container and style it as follows then place it anywhere I want in the source:

```
<div id="sm2-container" style="width:1px; height:1px; visibility: hidden" class="movieContainer sm2_debug" >
  
</div>
```

The real useful style is visibilty hidden because it is just an swf square with white background and I want to hide it.